# Union of nested open set and support of a singular (co)chain

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Assume $M$ is a union of nested open subsets $U_{\alpha}$, then why any compact subset in $M$ (in particular, the support of a singular (co)chain) is contained in some $U_{\alpha}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $K\subseteq M$ is compact, then the sets $U_\alpha\cap K$ are an open cover of $K$.  Since $K$ is compact, there is a finite subcover, and since the $U_\alpha$ are nested, this means $K$ is just contained in the largest $U_\alpha$ in the finite subcover.

(By the way, the support of a singular cochain need not be compact.  For instance, you can have a $0$-cochain that sends every point in $M$ to $1$.)

Comment: But is the support of a cycle contained in a compact subset of $M$?

Comment: Yes, a cycle is a sum of finitely many maps $\Delta^n\to M$, and the image of any such map is compact.